# mp3 file not streaming however no errors

Tags: ios, swift, mp3, avplayer

This file is not playing as an mp3 file, I am not sure where I messed up in my code.  The println statement is printed.

```
let urlString = "http://anything2mp3.com/system/files/mp3/Siberian%20Husky%20gets%20ICE%20POOL%20Extended_q1zY1dp1_ig_youtube.mp3"


@IBAction func tempPlay(sender: AnyObject) {

    println("runningtemp")
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    var avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    avPlayer.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to declare your AVPlayer out of your IBAction.

```
let urlString = "http://anything2mp3.com/system/files/mp3/Siberian%20Husky%20gets%20ICE%20POOL%20Extended_q1zY1dp1_ig_youtube.mp3"

var avPlayer:AVPlayer!

@IBAction func tempPlay(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        avPlayer.play()
    }
}
```